# Is it allowed to use child routes without router outlets? (tab contents inside main component)

Tags: angular, routes, router-outlet

Is it possible render different components for every tab for a tab menu without using router outlets? I have a parent component in which template there is a tab menu component, and every tab item has a ng template with the component for each tab. In the routing module I have specified tabs paths as children of parent route and seems it is working.

But I am not sure if children routes are only meant to be used in conjunction with router outlets with the aim to render things inside a parent component.

Comment: You can use child components without using router-outlet. It depends on the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your structure.

Documentation claims, that `router-outlet` is placeholder to render components, basing on router state.

If your current URL will match against only one component:

```
path: 'some/long/nested/path',
component: SomeComponent
```

then single `<router-outlet>` will fit.

If you wish to structure a bit more your routing configuration, it can be achieved as well with `children` array:

```
path: 'some'
children: [
  {
    path: 'long'
    children: [
      path: 'nested/path'
      component: SomeComponent
    ]
  }
]
```

Note, that above configuration orders a bit long, messy paths, but still, relation components to router-outlets that shall render them is 1:1 ratio. At this point you are still not limited to single component as well:

```
path: 'some'
children: [
  {
    path: 'long'
    children: [
      {
        path: 'nested/path'
        component: SomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'nested/path2'
        component: SomeComponent2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And now is the breakpoint: you wish to display component within component, like:

- `mybussiness-site/details/address`
- `mybussiness-site/details/contact`

Assuming, that details will be component itself, i.e.

```
<div> Details </div>

<p>This is details of my business, enjoy</p>

Here is the place, that address or contact will be displayed
```

Then, if in your parent component, there is a place, where other components will be displayed dynamically, based on URL, then you need `<router-outlet>` for them. As routing configuration would look like following in above example:

path: 'mybussiness-site/details'
component: DetailsMainComponent
children: [
{
path: 'address',
component: AddressComponent
},
{
path: 'contact',
component: ContactCOmponent
}
]

From configuration above, you see, that `DetailsComponent` is a parent for both `AddressCOmponent` and `ContactComponent` not only in terms of URL structure, but is also a host for them. Without URL routing, parent-child structure you could achive this in plain template by `*ngIf`-ing, like:

```
<div> Details </div>

<p>This is details of my business, enjoy</p>

<ng-contaier *ngIf="addressIsActive">
  <address-component></address-component>
</ng-component>

<ng-contaier *ngIf="contactIsActive">
  <contact-component></contact-component>
</ng-component>
```

But it's hideous and does not provide domain-separation, like URLs.

tl;dr:
If you route match just a single, one and only component, no additional routing outlet is needed, as you are using children probably only as a way of structurizing & organizing your paths configuration.

If your URL requires you  to render components one in another, dynamically, depending on URL, then probably parent component needs additional routing outlet to "spit out" children in right place.

Additional references to look for would be:

- Componentless Routes
- Content projection